# Python Remove duplicates from csv if value in column duplicated

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I am trying to write csv parser so if i have the same name in the name column i will delete the second name's line. For example:

```
['CSE_MAIN\\LC-CSEWS61', 'DEREGISTERED', '2018-04-18-192446'],
['CSE_MAIN\\IT-Laptop12', 'DEREGISTERED', '2018-03-28-144236'],
['CSE_MAIN\\LC-CSEWS61', 'DEREGISTERED', '2018-03-28-144236']]
```

I need that the last line will be deleted because it has the same name as the first one.

What i wrote is:

```
file2 = str(sys.argv[2])
print ("The first file is:" + file2)
reader2 = csv.reader (open(file2))
with open("result2.csv",'wb') as result2:
    wtr2= csv.writer( result2 )
    for r in reader2:
        wtr2.writerow( (r[0], r[6], r[9] ))
newreader2 = csv.reader (open("result2.csv"))
sortedlist2 = sorted(newreader2, key=lambda col: col[2] , reverse = True)
for i in range(len(sortedlist2)):
    for j in range(len(sortedlist2)-1):
        if (sortedlist2[i][0] == sortedlist2[j+1][0] and sortedlist2[i][1]!=sortedlist2[j+1][1]):
            if(sortedlist2[i][1]>sortedlist2[j+1][1]):
                del sortedlist2[i][0-2]
            else:
                del sortedlist2[j+1][0-2]
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are deleting list entries (del sortedlist2[i]). This way it is not written to a new file yet. Print sortedlist2. So you see what is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/name_file.csv')
df = df.drop_duplicates([0]) #0 this is columns which will compare.
df.to_csv('New_file.csv') #save to csv
```

This method delete all duplicates from columns 1.

If you need simple delete you can use method drop.

```
#You file after use pandas (print(df)):
            0                    1                 2
0   CSE_MAIN\LC-CSEWS61     DEREGISTERED    2018-04-18-192446
1   CSE_MAIN\IT-Laptop12    DEREGISTERED    2018-03-28-144236
2   CSE_MAIN\LC-CSEWS61     DEREGISTERED    2018-03-28-144236
```

For example you need delete 2 row.

```
df.drop(2,axis=0, inplace=True) #axis=0 means row, if you switch 1 this is columns.
```

Output:

```
              0                  1                 2
0   CSE_MAIN\LC-CSEWS61     DEREGISTERED    2018-04-18-192446
1   CSE_MAIN\IT-Laptop12    DEREGISTERED    2018-03-28-144236
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i meant that i will delete row only if there is same name. in my example pandas should iterate threw the names and only if there is a duplicated name it will delete the second

Comment: Mmm... so be it)

Comment: Oh) I think your need change 1 to 0 in `df.drop_duplicates([0])`. I fixed it. Try again.